Merge the legend from ggpattern and ggplot2
I have a world map where countries are colored and some colors also have stripes (so that it is ready when printed in black and white).
I managed to add the stripes using the package ggpattern, but I haven't succeeded in merging the legend of ggplot2 and ggpattern: how can I include the stripes in the legend for colors, and remove the legend for patterns?
Here is a minimum reproducible example with only two colors (which takes a lot of time to run, for some reason).
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpattern)

breaks <- c(-Inf, 0, Inf)
labels <- c("negative", "positive")
world_map <- map_data(map = "world")
data <- data.frame(country_map = unique(world_map$region))
data$mean <- -1
data$mean[data$country_map == "Russia"] <- 1
data$group <- cut(data$mean, breaks = breaks, labels = labels)
data$pattern <- ifelse(data$mean < 0, "stripe", NA)

ggplot(data) + geom_map(aes(map_id = country_map, fill = fct_rev(group)), map = world_map) + #coord_proj("+proj=robin", xlim = c(-135, 178.5), ylim = c(-56, 84)) + 
  geom_polygon(data = world_map, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), colour = 'grey', size = 0,  fill = NA) + expand_limits(x = world_map$long, y = world_map$lat) + theme_void() + 
  geom_map_pattern(data = data, map = world_map, aes(map_id = country_map, pattern = pattern), pattern_fill = "black", fill = NA, pattern_density = 0.1, pattern_angle = 30, pattern_spacing = 0.02) #+
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Group", drop = FALSE, values = c("red", "blue"), labels = labels)




You could turn off the fill guide and override the aesthetics of the pattern :
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpattern)

breaks <- c(-Inf, 0, Inf)
labels <- c("negative", "positive")
world_map <- map_data(map = "world")
data <- data.frame(country_map = unique(world_map$region))
data$mean <- -1
data$mean[data$country_map == "Russia"] <- 1
data$group <- cut(data$mean, breaks = breaks, labels = labels)
pattern <- c("negative" = "stripe", "positive" = "none")

ggplot(data) + 
  geom_map(aes(map_id = country_map, fill = fct_rev(group)), map = world_map) + 
  geom_polygon(data = world_map, 
               aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), 
               colour = 'grey', size = 0,  fill = NA) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("negative" = "#abcdef", "positive" = "#fedcba")) +
  geom_map_pattern(data = data, 
                   map = world_map, 
                   aes(map_id = country_map, pattern = group),
                   pattern_alpha = 1,
                   fill = "transparent",
                   pattern_fill = "black",
                   pattern_colour = "black",
                   pattern_density = .1,
                   pattern_key_scale_factor = .5)+
  scale_pattern_manual(values = pattern)+
  guides(fill = "none",
        pattern = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = c("negative" = "#abcdef", "positive" = "#fedcba" )))) 


Another approach that includes restricting plot limits as asked in original (pre-edited) post:
library(rnaturalearth)
world_sf <- ne_countries(returnclass = "sf")

library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.0, GDAL 3.5.3, PROJ 9.1.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(ggpattern)
#> Warning: package 'ggpattern' was built under R version 4.3.3

# check bounding box of Robinson projection; note units are meters
sf::st_transform(world_sf, '+proj=robin') |> st_bbox()
#>      xmin      ymin      xmax      ymax 
#> -16810131  -8625155  16810131   8343004

# set (approximate) desired plot limits in meters
x_lim <- c(-16810131 / 180 * 135, 16810131 / 180 * 178.5)
y_lim <- c(-8625155 / 90 * 56, 8343004 / 90 * 84)

world_sf |> 
  # add column to use for coloring and patterns
  mutate(is_russia = name_en == 'Russia') |> 
  ggplot() +    
  geom_sf_pattern(
    aes(fill = is_russia, pattern = is_russia), 
  ) +
  coord_sf(
    crs = '+proj=robin',
    xlim = x_lim,
    ylim = y_lim
  )


Created on 2024-06-17 with reprex v2.0.2
[EDIT: I just noticed I used two different versions of the Robinson projection; consistent now.]
And a useful reference for plot limits:
https://datascience.blog.wzb.eu/2019/04/30/zooming-in-on-maps-with-sf-and-ggplot2/

+1 from me for using an sf object. The slow plotting experienced by the other solutions is a result of having to plot the 99,338 coordinates in map_data(). On a relatively low-spec Win10 machine, your solution plots in ~10 seconds, ~42 seconds for the accepted answer. Not necessarily a like-for-like comparison given the default ne_countries() data are fairly low res, but yours is plotting as Robinson so potentially some added cost there. And  at world scale, it is not an issue anyway.

If I could, I'd add another +1 for offering proof of what happens with the axis ticks when plotting a Robinson projection. Getting them to display on the y-axis requires extra steps and I knew it was due to the 'curved' axis, but this has clarified the whole thing. It never occurred to me to apply xlim/ylim on a Robinson (kinda defeats its purpose) but your example clearly shows only the graticules that touch the plot extent get plotted. I just went with coord_sf(crs = '+proj=robin', expand = FALSE) to get the full map.

Thanks, @LTyrone, the global behavior is unexpected, but I guess in keeping with the default pairing of ticks and major grid lines used by ggplot().

My answer to this question highlights the issue well I think. It's almost as if there are two plot extents in one (as far as I can tell).

Another potential option:
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpattern)

breaks <- c(-Inf, 0, Inf)
labels <- c("negative", "positive")
world_map <- map_data(map = "world")
data <- data.frame(country_map = unique(world_map$region))
data$mean <- -1
data$mean[data$country_map == "Russia"] <- 1
data$group <- cut(data$mean, breaks = breaks, labels = labels)
data$pattern <- ifelse(data$mean < 0, "stripe", NA)

ggplot(data) + 
  geom_map(aes(map_id = country_map, fill = fct_rev(group)), map = world_map) + 
  geom_polygon(data = world_map, 
               aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), 
                   colour = 'grey', linewidth = 0,  fill = NA) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("negative" = "blue", "positive" = "red")) +
  geom_map_pattern(data = data, 
                   map = world_map, 
                   aes(map_id = country_map, pattern = group),
                   fill = "transparent",
                   pattern_fill = "black",
                   pattern_density = .1,
                   pattern_key_scale_factor = .5)+
  scale_pattern_manual(values = c("negative" = "stripe", positive = "none"))+
  guides(fill = "none", 
         pattern = guide_legend(override.aes = list(
           pattern = c("stripe", "none"),
           fill = c("negative" = "blue", "positive" = "red"))))


Created on 2024-06-17 with reprex v2.1.0
I don't know about the coord_proj("+proj=robin", xlim = c(-135, 178.5), ylim = c(-56, 84)) + sorry.

Does it run fast on your computer? I've executed these lines one hour ago and it's still running...

It took 5 mins on my computer - are you running it in a new session? That's a surprising amount of time

Indeed, after I clear the environment, it "only" takes 5 min. How come?

There's a lot going on 'behind the scenes' here, and you might be running out of resources (e.g. going into swap, I/O disk bound, etc). Regardless, I'm glad you solved your issue :)
